# How to stop overlapping of x-axis text over each other after page refresh in google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-visualization

I have one google chart at [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jaikratsingh/85u5z1q8/). I have few input fields on my page also and when ever there is any validation fail happens I see my google chart something like below.[image: Image from local]

NOTE : - I do not have any input field in my jsfiddle that is only for your refrence. If you want to make any of your changes and see the result.

How to stop this overlapping. On first time page load everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not seeing this on jsfiddle.  I wonder if there is a javascript error that occurs when there are validation errors after the page has loaded.  Try checking your console for errors.

Comment: Yes, on jsfiddle it is not happening. There even page refresh is first time hit like. That is for your ref so that you can test your changes and you do not ned to create your example from scratch.

Comment: You need to provide an example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Length of text will make it overlap, naturally as starting point of next text is before the previous text ends

Solutions:

1. Make texts vertical
2. Bars are colored so put a list below the chart of what color represents what item
3. Use tooltip on bar which will show the text when you hover on the bar
4. Use wide horizontal axis for the graph to accommodate values below

   Use of Solution 1 if you have space constraint as mentioned in your comment
   [image: Verticle Lables]

Comment: Thanks for replying Heena but I have some size(area) constraint on my page.

Comment: @Jaikrat Use of verticle lables solution can use bar space too if worst comes to worst. Instead of text overlap text, text overlap bar will not be problem. I could have put background for text in another color for better readability but look of graph suffers in that. You can experiment with colors and font sizes to suit you.  Hope it helps

Comment: Idea is good but as you can see my question is months old thats why we used fusioncharts. But thanks a lot anyways.